# Form submit jquery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, mobile

I have got a form which is set up in a jquery mobile page. My problem is that I can not submit the info with the form. I am new with jquery. 
Every suggestion is welcomed.

Comment: I think someone should make canyoushowussomecode.com just like there's a whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: @ExplosionPills And shortcuts for comment textarea.

Comment: I have done some codes, but I did not want to show them here because I thought they were wrong.

Comment: Showing some incorrect code is always much more welcome than showing no code. If it's wrong, it doesn't matter - that's why you're here asking a question about it!

Comment: Show it anyway. If your code was correct, you wouldn't be asking for help now, would you?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#form").submit();
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a1/experiments/api-viewer/docs/submit/index.html

Answer (score 1):

The form can be submit using jquery :

```
$("#formId").submit();
```